# How to reroute MOQ call?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Trying to mock the following interface, but finding the syntax really awkward to work with.

```
public interface IKvpStoreRepository
{
    string this[string key] { get; set; }

    Task<bool> ContainsKey(string key);
}
```

Now I'm hoping to record the value into a backing store as below:

```
var backingStore = new Dictionary<string,string>();
var mockKvpRepository = new Mock<IKvpStoreRepository>();
mockKvpRepository.
    Setup(_ => _[It.IsAny<string>()] = It.IsAny<Task<string>>()) //BROKE [1]
    .Callback((key,value) => backingStore[key] = value) //??? [2]
    .ReturnsAsync("blah"); //??? [3]
```

[1] Expression tree may not contain assignment.

[2] How do I get both key and value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test passes.

```
[Test]
public void q35387809() {
    var backingStore = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var mockKvpRepository = new Mock<IKvpStoreRepository>();

    mockKvpRepository.SetupSet(x => x["blah"] = It.IsAny<string>())
        .Callback((string name, string value) => { backingStore[name] = value; });

    mockKvpRepository.Object["blah"] = "foo";

    backingStore.Count.Should().Be(1);
    backingStore["blah"].Should().Be("foo");
}
```

Comment: stuard, thanks for replying. Can you clarify if I can use variable eg. `x[It.IsAny<string>()>]`? I want it to call through.